# How to change proxy settings in Android (especially in Chrome)

Tags: android, proxy, ip

Could you please help me: is it possible to set proxy settings in Android (especially in Chrome)? I have to change IP on Android during the testing. Or there is some soft which can help me to solve this issue...

Answer (score 187, accepted):

Found one solution for WIFI (works for Android 4.3, 4.4):

1. Connect to WIFI network (e.g. 'Alex')
2. Settings->WIFI
3. Long tap on connected network's name (e.g. on 'Alex')
4. Modify network config-> Show advanced options
5. Set proxy settings

Comment: Helps to setup a ssh proxy first with sshtunnel then use localhost as the proxy address. No root access required either...

Comment: @maksim Alekseychik, When you do that, it says it will change your IP for only browsers, not for apps. Is there a way to change the IP that apps on the android work?

Comment: This is solution not only for browser, but for all device's apps.

Comment: It is not working for 10.87.*.* local IPs in android chrome. I just want to bypass proxy server and directly connect to this 10.87.*.* IPs. working in native android browser not in chrome.

Comment: I tried this but only my webbrowser could connect internet while other apps couldn't. how to fix it

Comment: How can we do it programmatically

Comment: Is there any app tool to do this job more easily?

Comment: It is working for Wi-Fi. What in case of Mobile data? Please mention.

Comment: How do you set the proxy credentials?

Comment: It doesn't work for me, as I don't connect to a wifi network - I tether mobile data to via wifi to a PC and want the PC to be proxy for my phone :(

Comment: The global proxy setup on Android can be done via [ADB](https://gist.github.com/rwp0/a7d3f258ff0a50ef2bcdcd4a50485755) but there seem to be no native Android UI for it.