# Locally hosted sites not accessible over WiFi

Tags: dns, wifi, local, lan

MacBook connected on university network through Ethernet with the following settings.

> ```
> Configure IPv4: Using DHCP
> IP Address: 172.17.15.146
> Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
> Router: 172.17.15.254
> DNS Server: 172.24.2.71
> ```

Shared my Ethernet connection over WiFi for my android phone.

> ```
> IP address: 192.168.2.2
> IP settings: Using DHCP
> ```

Googling MyIP through both devices give the following.

> ```
> Your public IP address: 202.78.172.162
> ```

Local sites like `library/` and `news/` only accessible over 1st device.
Is there a way to access these sites on the 2nd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proxy server on your MacBook will probably let you do what you want.  It's a little more involved than file sharing, but things like http://squidman.net/squidman/ can make it a little easier.

After setting up the proxy server, you'll want to [set your Android up to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21068905/how-to-change-proxy-settings-in-android-especially-in-chrome).  You'll want to use the local NAT address of your MacBook (likely 192.168.2.1).