# Jmeter script Recording

Tags: jmeter

What is the purpose of JMeter Recorder? With Work Bench, how can I record a Script for Android Native application? I need to record a Script for Native application, is that possible, and how can find errors for Tested Application? What is the procedure to do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test Android app in JMeter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37320813/how-to-test-android-app-in-jmeter)

Answer (score 0):

If your application is using [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) or [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) protocols you can record its network activity using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

1. First of all make sure JMeter and Android device are on the same network (i.e. connected to the same Wi-Fi) and the machine running JMeter is not blocking port 8888 in the firewall
2. Prepare JMeter for recording. The fastest way is using [JMeter Templates](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#test_plan_building) feature. From JMeter's main menu choose `File -> Templates -> Recording -> Create`, expand `Workbench -> HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder` and click Start button
3. Optional step (if your application is using HTTPS only). Locate **ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt** file under JMeter's "bin" folder, send it to yourself by email, open the email on Android device and install the certificate from the attachment
4. Configure Android device to use JMeter as a proxy. Use IP address or hostname of machine running JMeter as a proxy host and `8888` as a proxy port. Depending on your application network transport and Android version you may have to use a 3rd-party tool like [Proxy Droid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.proxydroid&hl=en) to set up the proxy configuration
5. Start your application - JMeter should capture the network requests under the [Recording Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller).

---

In case if you experience any problems update the question with the exact errors. Also it worth checking out [A Step by Step Guide to Performance Testing on Native Mobile Apps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/step-step-guide-performance-testing-native-mobile-apps) for an alternative solution.