# Retrofit2 with local Tor HTTP proxy does not adapt to Tor-circuit change

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, http-proxy, tor

Im using Retrofit2 in my Android project and configure it's okhttp3 client with the [netcipher](https://github.com/guardianproject/NetCipher) library's StrongOkHttpClientBuilder to use the local HTTP proxy (127.0.0.1:8118) provided by the [Orbot](https://guardianproject.info/apps/orbot/) application in the background.

For testing purpose, I create for every request a new Retrofit2 client (with new Okhttp3 client) and send a request to http://api.ipify.org/ to verify the current public IP.
Everything is working fine, the connection goes through the local Tor proxy and the public IP I get as response from ipify.org is an IP from the Tor network.

BUT: When I change the circuit in Orbot manually, so that the local proxy resolves to a different Tor-network IP and test again, the oldTor-network IP gets used...
Has anyone an idea, what could be the reason for this? Maybe the way how okhttp3 is processing proxies?

Notes:
- Removing the local proxy in Retrofit2 and retry, it resolves correctly to my normal public IP
- It's not an Orbot issue, because when I configure 127.0.0.1:8118 as [browser proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21068905/how-to-change-proxy-settings-in-android-especially-in-chrome) and change the circuit it works (public IP changes)
- It shouldn't be a Retrofit caching problem, because I haven't configured cache and for every new try I build the Retrofit and okhttp3 client new.