# How to check if Proxy is Enabled in Android?

Tags: android, proxy

How to check if Proxy is Enabled in Android. So that when I hit the API request should not show in JMeter and also the response should not display in JMeter.
How to tackle this Problem?

Comment: Did you try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21068905/how-to-change-proxy-settings-in-android-especially-in-chrome ?

Comment: @George Rylkov you got me wrong. Testers are changing the Proxy as per your provided link. What I want to do is Restrict Proxy or Detect if proxy ip is been entered in Android. How to overcome with it?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/3N5NRQJJ
Try this

Comment: I also need this. Have you figured it out?