# For mobile aap recording using blazemeternot able to open http:\\bz for certificate installation

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

I am using " ( http://a.blazemeter.com/app/recorder/index.html)" for mobile app recording but not able to open http:\bz  to get certificate installed in my android device. Need help to get certificate from http:\bz

Comment: Go to $JMETER_HOME/bin directory, you will find ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt file. add to your mobile device

Answer (score 0):

1. Open [BlazeMeter Proxy Recorder](https://a.blazemeter.com/app/recorder/index.html) application and click "Create Proxy"

   [image: BlazeMeter Create Proxy]
2. The proxy will be created and you will see its host and port separated by a semicolon:

   [image: Blazemeter Prory host and port]
3. [Modify your Android device proxy settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21069032/2897748) and set proxy host and port according to what you see in the step 2
4. Open `http://bz` URL in your favourite browser

See [BlazeMeter Mobile Recorder](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420545-BlazeMeter-Proxy-Recorder-Mobile-and-web-#mobile) for detailed instructions. If above steps don't resolve your issue I would suggest contacting [BlazeMeter Support](https://www.blazemeter.com/support)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, I am getting DNS error on http://bz page(bz’s server DNS address could not be found.).