# Android Studio proxy settings not working with emulator

Tags: android-studio, proxy, android-studio-3.0

I'm running an Android emulator (v8.1) with the AVD manager in Android Studio (v3.1.1) on a Mac, and my machine runs behind a proxy.

I can change the emulator proxy settings and browse around by following this post: [How to change proxy settings in Android (especially in Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21068905/how-to-change-proxy-settings-in-android-especially-in-chrome)

But instead of changing the settings on the emulator directly, I'd ideally like to use the Android Studio proxy settings as such:

- Update the proxy auto-config URL (*Preferences* -> *System Settings* -> *HTTP Proxy*)
- Start the Android emulator
- On the right-side bar go to *Settings* -> *Proxy*
- Check "use Android Studio HTTP Proxy Settings" then browse merrily

Unfortunately this hasn't worked, any ideas why the Android Studio proxy settings don't transfer to the emulator?